# Game Maker Studio Master Collection compile error

Tags: compilation

I have downloaded all the android sdk platforms and api in full. Have got the jdk and ndk. But when i compile my project to apk, it says that :

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 38 seconds

jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size ( expected 3251 bytes but got 3309 bytes )
cmd /c ""\Download\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows..\tools\zipalign" -v4 "

"D:\Download\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows..\tools\zipalign" is not an recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How to solve this and get the apk?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cleaning the target is usefull, if its not, you should download android studio, and search for "Standalone API" download every single API and make a folder on C:\, ("SDK"), then in GM:S goto settings and set the path to the SDK folder. Good Luck!